# Asp Checkboxlist Loses Values After PostBack

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

I have a checkboxlist control that I need to check the values of when a Submit button is clicked by the user onscreen(C#).
This checkboxlist is part of a user control that I am referencing within my page markup.
However, when I check the values of the checkboxlist within the code of the submit button, all of the values are gone (i.e it says there are no items at all in the checkboxlist control).
Anyone know why this would be happening? I am doing the exact same thing in code in another place with another checkboxlist user control and it works perfectly.

I don't have my exact code to hand but below is a simplified version of what I am doing.
Basically I am binding data to the Checkboxlist only when it is NOT a postback on the usedr control.

```
USER CONTROL WHICH CONTAINS ONLY THE CHECKBOXLIST CONTROL Page_Load()
If(!IsPostBack)
{
   foreach(var item in myVals)
   {
      ListItem i = new ListItem();
      i.Text = item.Text;
      i.Value = item.Value;
      i.Selected = false;

      myCheckBoxListControl.Add(i);
   }
}
```

Now I have a submit button function which checks the values in the checkboxlist...

```
SubmitButton_Click()
{
   foreach(ListItem item in myCheckBoxListControl.Items)
   {
      // process each one here. The code never gets in here as there are never any items in the checkboxlist
   }
}
```

Anyone know why the CheckboxList has lost all of its items by the time the submit button function gets executed? The checkboxlist has EnableViewState set to true.